# i want to convert my clac.py and calc.kv file to app

Tags: python, android, kivy

i want to convert my python and kivy files to an app but the thing is i dont want to use virtual machine or linux or ubuntu i am on windows 10 and i want to convert it for free please help me and tell if any questions
here is my  calc.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Window.size = (500,700)
Builder.load_file('calc.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
     def clear (self):
         self.ids.calc_input.text = "0"
     def button_press(self, button):
         prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
         if prior == "0":
             self.ids.calc_input.text = ''
             #self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{Button}'
         else:
             self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior}{button}'
     def  math_sign(self, sign):
         prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
         self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior}{sign}'

     def remove(self):
          prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
          prior = prior [:-1]
          self.ids.calc_input.text = prior

     def dot(self):
         prior = self.ids.calc_input.text 
         num_list = prior.split("+")
         num_list[-1]
         if "+" in prior and "." not in num_list[-1]:
            prior = f'{prior}.'
         self.ids.calc_input.text = prior                  
         if "." in prior:
            pass
         else:
            prior = f'{prior}.'
         self.ids.calc_input.text = prior

     def equals(self):
         
            prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
            answer = eval(prior)
            self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer) 


            '''
            if "+" in prior:
             num_list = prior.split("+")
             answer = 0.0
             for number in num_list:
                 answer = answer + float(number)
                 
                 
                 self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
                 
            if "-" in prior:
             num_list = prior.split("-")
             answer = 0.0
             for number in num_list:
                 answer = answer - float(number)
                 
                 
                 self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
                 
            if "x" in prior:
             num_list = prior.split("*")
             answer = 0.0
             for number in num_list:
                 answer = answer * float(number)
                 
                 
                 self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
                 
            if "/" in prior:
             num_list = prior.split("/")
             answer = 0.0
             for number in num_list:
                 answer = answer / float(number)
                 
                 
                 self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
                 
                 #self.ids.text = answer
            '''
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     App().run()
```

here is my calc.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<WindowManager>:
    Screen1


<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        TextInput:
            id: calc_input
            text: "0"
            halign: "right"
            font_size : 65
            size_hint: (1, .15)

        GridLayout:
            cols:4
            rows:5

#            Button:
#                size_hint: (.2, .2)
#                font_size: 32
#                text: "%"

            Button:

                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "<<<"
                on_press : root.remove()


            Button:
                id: clear
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "C"
                on_press : root.clear()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "/"
                on_press : root.math_sign("/")


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "7"
                on_press : root.button_press(7)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "8"
                on_press : root.button_press(8)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "9"
                on_press : root.button_press(9)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "x"
                on_press : root.math_sign("*")


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "4"
                on_press : root.button_press(4)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "5"
                on_press : root.button_press(5)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "6"
                on_press : root.button_press(6)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "-"
                on_press : root.math_sign("-")


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "1"
                on_press : root.button_press(1)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "2"
                on_press : root.button_press(2)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "3"
                on_press : root.button_press(3)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "+"
                on_press : root.math_sign("+")

#            Button:
 #               size_hint: (.2, .2)
  #              font_size: 32
   #             text: "+/-"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "0"
                on_press : root.button_press(0)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "."
                on_press : root.dot()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "="
                on_press :root.equals()
```

even i had tried using google collab but that dint work , the app was crashing as soon as it started

Answer (score 0):

`the app was crashing as soon as it started`, I supposed that you used `Pyinstaller` because you tried it on Windows ?

I suppose that you were able to create the `exe` because you didn't showed error message of Pyinstaller installation crashing ?

I suppose you may want to have the logs of the error to debug it ?

So I suppose that you want to not double click on the `exe` to launch it but launch it from a terminal to keep the logs.

So your title should be **Kivy: How to get logs of a crashing .exe created with Pyinstaller on Windows**.

**EDIT:**

So you wanted to create an .apk on Windows. This is not possible with kivy. You have to do it on Linux.

If you want to see what is happening, connect your phone to your computer and use `buildozer android deploy run logcat`.

Comment: i think you got it wrong because my app format is .apk

Comment: Hum, if I remember well, you can't build .apk with buildozer on Windows. This is why I was thinking you wanted to create an .exe. If you want to create an .apk, do it on Linux.

Comment: your title should be **Kivy: How to get logs of a crashing .apk created with Buildozer on Windows.** which people would have answered you can't create .apk on Windows.

Comment: but dont want to use virtual machine

Comment: "but dont want to use virtual machine" ? Go for a dual boot ? borrow your brother Linux PC ? or use a virtual machine. I won't make buildozer available in windows for you bro :)

Comment: ok now i have  decided  to use vm so can you guide me what are the steps to create app by that method?

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kivy+buildozer